# Há três ou mais modos do verbo em português?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Tenho visto informação contraditória em relação à categoria gramatical do modo.

1. Em Cunha&Cintra é dito que os modos do verbo são três (a maioria dos resultados na internet seguem esta divisão):

   > **Modos.**
   >
   > Há três modos em português: o **INDICATIVO**, o **CONJUNTIVO**, e o **IMPERATIVO**.
   >
   > "Nova gramática do português contemporâneo", Cunha&Cintra, 17ª edição 2002.
2. Há uma outra perspectiva que é considerar também [o **Condicional** um modo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/condicional-presente/13819) se seguirmos a norma portuguesa em vez da brasileira para o futuro do pretérito. (Este post é da autoria da Edite Prada que cita várias referências.)
3. Há ainda outra contagem, menos comum (pelo menos nos resultados do google), de considerar todas as habituais divisões do verbo como um modo. Por exemplo, nesta página da RTP dizem que [**Infinitivo**, **Gerúndio**, **Particípio** e **Condicional** também são modos](https://ensina.rtp.pt/explicador/tempos-e-modos-verbais/). (Este artigo é da autoria de Sandra Duarte Tavares.)

Há alguma acordo sobre isto? Por exemplo, se usarmos a norma portuguesa de elencar o **Condicional** ele é necessariamente um modo? As formas nomiais também podem ou devem ser consideradas modos?

Comment: A Gramática do Português da Gulbenkian tem um capítulo inteiro sobre o assunto; mais um sobre modalidade. Ao que parece, o imperativo, indicativo e conjuntivo são consensuais, mas depois há outros defendidos nalgumas gramáticas, mas não noutras. Vou estudar melhor aquilo, quando tiver tempo; depois te direi mais alguma coisa, se ainda for necessário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definição de modos verbais pode variar de acordo com a gramática em questão e também com a tradição linguística de cada região. No entanto, em geral, a maioria das gramáticas considera apenas três modos verbais: Indicativo, Subjuntivo (ou Conjuntivo) e Imperativo.

No caso específico do Condicional, a tradição linguística portuguesa o classifica como um tempo verbal, enquanto a tradição linguística brasileira o classifica como um modo verbal. Isso se deve ao fato de que, em Portugal, o Condicional é formado a partir do Futuro do Pretérito (que é um tempo verbal), enquanto no Brasil é formado a partir do Subjuntivo Imperfeito (que é uma forma verbal do modo Subjuntivo). Portanto, a contagem dos modos verbais pode variar de acordo com a tradição linguística seguida.

Em relação às formas nominais do verbo (Infinitivo, Gerúndio e Particípio), elas não são consideradas modos verbais, mas sim formas verbais com funções específicas. O Infinitivo é uma forma nominal que pode funcionar como substantivo, adjetivo ou advérbio. O Gerúndio é uma forma nominal que indica uma ação em andamento. Já o Particípio pode ser utilizado para formar tempos compostos e também pode ter funções adjetivas.

Em resumo, a maioria das gramáticas considera apenas três modos verbais (Indicativo, Subjuntivo e Imperativo), mas a classificação pode variar de acordo com a tradição linguística seguida. As formas nominais do verbo não são consideradas modos verbais, mas sim formas verbais com funções específicas.